# how to enable or disable pointer events for a specific part of an element?

Tags: html, css

i am wondering if is it possible to disable pointer event for say half of an element not entirely? for example like picture below..

[image]

maybe it would be possible to use another element to overlap that part of element that i want to be disabled but as far as i realized it is impossible through any straight way but we can cover that part of image by another div and then it'll do the trick...

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that we should put our image in a container then set its position to fixed now let's check it out

```css
#container{
    position:fixed;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:5;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#container img{
width:100%;
height:100%;
cursor:pointer;
}
#imgcover{
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    height:250px;
    width:150px;
    left:50px;
    top:8px;
    transform:rotate(45deg)
}
```

and html codes

```html
   <div id="container">
        <div id="imgcover"></div>
        <a href="/"><img src="/forum_corner03.png" /></a>
    </div>
```